# Is w(x), with integral over [a, b] = 1, and for which the division of two integrals of functions weighted by w(x) is maximal, a dirac delta in [a, b]?

Tags: calculus

Is $w(x)$ with

- $\int_a^b{w(x)dx}=1$
- $\frac{\int_a^b{f(x)w(x)dx}}{\int_a^b{g(x)w(x)dx}}$ reaches a maximum

a dirac delta in [a, b]?

Intuitively, I'd say yes, but I'm not sure and my math currently isn't up to (dis)proving it.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by maximal?

Typically the Dirac delta satisfies $\int_a^b f(x) \delta(x-x_0) dx = f(x_0)$. Strictly speaking, one uses an "approximation to the identity" to recover the behavior of the Dirac delta.

Comment: I meant that it reaches a maximum, I edited the question. Does this clarify it?

Comment: I guess in words you could also say: there exists an c in [a, b] for which f(c)/g(c) is greater than any $\frac{\int_a^b{f(x)w(x)dx}}{\int_a^b{g(x)w(x)dx}}$ with $\int_a^b{w(x)dx}=1$.

Comment: If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are constants, then the expression does not depend on the form of $w$, so there is no requirement to be a Dirac delta function.

Comment: But f(x) and g(x) are functions in x?

Comment: How about when $f(x)=g(x)$?

Comment: The point is that your answer will depend on the functions $f$ and $g$

Comment: Could it perhaps be true that IF there is a maximum, that this maximum can be reached with $w(x)$ a dirac delta (and perhaps other functions as well). I take it that you do not share my intuition?

Comment: The quantity $\frac{\int_a^b f(x) w(x) dx}{\int_a^b g(x) w(x) dx}$ is a scalar. What are you optimizing over?

Comment: optimizing over w(x), maybe read the third comment in this thread, it reads a little easier. (altough it should say "greater than or equal to")

Comment: Is $w(x)\geq 0$ non-negative?